# How can I fix SQL Server Management Studio Report Services Role Browse is allowing security to be changed?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

The AD groups assigned to folders and reports have the browse roles, but they can change security.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SSRS manage security tab is showing for user with AD Groups having Browse Role](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31391936/ssrs-manage-security-tab-is-showing-for-user-with-ad-groups-having-browse-role)